# Table creation with multirow

Tags: tables

I don't know what is wrong with this tabular code

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}| } 
\centering
\hline
A & B & #Items & #Elements \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{4em}{MMM}     & AA  &  2 &  11 \\
                               & BB   &  1 &  26 \\
\hline    
\caption{Name}
\label{n}
\end{tabular}
```

Which produces

[image]

The table width is more than one column which is why you see [4] and [5]. I used this code based on the example [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables).

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does it help to (a) replace `#Items` and `#Elements` with `\#Items` and `\#Elements`, respectively, (b) execute `\centering` before rather than after  `\begin{tabular}`, (c) execute `\caption{Name} \label{n}` after rather than before `\end{tabular}`, and (d) encase the entire code block in a `table` environment?

Comment: It changed but it is still buggy. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLHAJ.png

Comment: I wouldn't call the fact that the final column is not wide enough a "bug". Instead, it's a simple mistake on your part, of not having made the final column wide enough. I'd try doubling the column's width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `\centering` inside a table like that (or if you do it will only work locally). If you want the columns centered, you need to add that to the colspec.

The character `#` is special in LaTeX and must be escaped.

A caption and label cannot be inside a tabular. It should either be in a table environment wrapping the tabular, if you want a float, or else you can use the `\captionof` command from the `\caption` package.

The contents you have don't fit in the widths you've assigned to the columns. I've adjusted the widths of the last two columns, but if you have more content, you may need to do more adjusting.

You can use = as the second argument to multirow to get the natural width.

Either (will float):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|}
\hline
A & B & \#Items & \#Elements \\
\hline
\multirow{2}={\centering MMM}     & AA  &  2 &  11 \\
\cline{2-4}% if you want a partial horizontal line here
                                  & BB  &  1 &  26 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Name}\label{n}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Or (will not float):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|}
\hline
A & B & \#Items & \#Elements \\
\hline
\multirow{2}={\centering MMM}     & AA  &  2 &  11 \\
\cline{2-4}% if you want a partial horizontal line here
                                  & BB  &  1 &  26 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\captionof{table}{Name}\label{n}

\end{document}
```

[image: table example]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you would like?

```
     \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|  } 
 \hline
 A & B & Items & Elements \\
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{4em}{MMM} & AA & 2 & 11 \\ 
 & BB & 1 & 26 \\  
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \captionof{table}{Name}\label{n}

 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code produces error: `LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.`

Comment: It seems to work for me. I must be doing something wrong but I can't see it as it renders what I wanted.

Comment: It's supposed to give you this error because `\caption{}` is not allowed outside environments such as `table` or `figure` etc. I checked [your code](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bjwxwvmgrxfb) on Overleaf and locally and the error is the same.

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the correct caption, that is `Table 1: Name` as it's supposed to, it only shows `Name`. It doesn't work!

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I was only trying to help. I think I have resolved the issue.

Comment: I am also learning here. To resolve this, you may need either tje environment as mentioned before or load the package `caption` and use `\captionof{table}{...}`. I'd also enclose the whole thing (the caption and the table including `\centering`) inside a group, e.g. `\bgroup...\egroup`

Comment: I'm sorry are you telling me that this still does not work?

Comment: It's working now